# upper bound of exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponentiation, exponential-sum

I am looking for a tight upper bound of exponential function (or sum of exponential functions):

$e^x<f(x)\;$ when $ \;x<0$ 
or

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} < g(x_1,...,x_n)\;$ when $\;x_i<0$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $x < 0$ then $e^x < 1$. Is this what you need?

Comment: What do you mean with $x$ is discrete?

Comment: Thanks Pragabhava, but I am looking for a tight upper bound of exponential function.

Comment: Thanks Pragabhava, but I am looking for a tight upper bound for exponential function. I know a close upper bound ($1/(1-x)$) , but I am looking for polynomial form!

Comment: Sorry, "x is discrete" was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Since you suggest in the comments you would like a polynomial bound, you can use any even Taylor polynomial for $e$.

**Proposition. $\boldsymbol{1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}}$ is an upper bound for $\boldsymbol{e^x}$ when $\boldsymbol{n}$ is even and $\boldsymbol{x \le 0}$.**

*Proof.*
We wish to show $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, where $f: (-\infty, 0] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function defined by
$f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!} - e^x.$
Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to - \infty$,
$f$ must attain an absolute minimum somewhere on the interval $(-\infty, 0]$.

- If $f$ has an absolute minimum at $0$, then for all $x$,
  $f(x) \ge f(0) = 1 - e^0 = 0$, so we are done.
- If $f$ has an absolute minimum at $y$ for some $y < 0$, then $f'(y) = 0$.
  But differentiating,
  $$
  f'(y) = 1 + y + \frac{y^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{y^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} - e^y
  = f(y) - \frac{y^n}{n!}.
  $$
  Therefore, for any $x$,
  $$
  f(x) \ge f(y) = \frac{y^n}{n!} + f'(y) = \frac{y^n}{n!} > 0,
  $$
  since $n$ is even.
  $\square$

---

Keep in mind that any polynomial upper bound will only be tight up to a certain point, because the polynomial will blow up to infinity as $x \to -\infty$.
Also note, the same proof shows that the Taylor polynomial is a *lower* bound for $e^x$ when $n$ is odd and $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 4):

For $x < 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$
0 < \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} < e^{-x}
$$

so

$$
e^x < 1\left/\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\right..
$$

Comment: For $x>0$, the first assertion is false. The series is alternating, so the even subsequence (ie for $n$ even) decreases to $e^{-x}$ so it cannot be smaller than its limit. However, the result remains true for $n$ odd, if the sum is not zero (it is never negative).

Comment: @zozoens, At the top of my answer I assume that $x < 0$, not that $x > 0$. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, and so does the OP. However, I stumbled upon this question while looking for such a bound for $x>0$ and your answer pleased me so I just wanted to complete it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

How about $e^{-x}\leq c(\gamma)(\frac{1}{1+x})^\gamma$ for non-negative $x$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? what is $\gamma$ and what is $c(\gamma)$? thanks

Comment: sorry, i didn't write that well! the idea is that the exponential grows faster than any polynomial. So the statement should be: for any $\gamma>0$ there exists a constant $c(\gamma)$ such that $e^{-x} \leq c(\gamma) (\frac{1}{1+x})^\gamma$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!